# What is the difference between 情势, 局势, 形势, 情形, 情况 and 状况?

Tags: meaning, difference

< 情势 situation; trend of events; circumstances:

局势 situation; state (of affairs)

形势 situation; circumstance; condition; state of affairs >

< 情形 circumstances; situation

情况 circumstances; situation >

状况 condition; state; situation

Very confused. They obviously have a subtle difference as with all the analogous words in English, but I can't get the handle of it.

Comment: 小马词典 has compounds for entries  (providing info about 意义 ＆ 用法）, 情况：实际／现实情况、具体情况、（在大多数）情况下、看情况、经济情况， no compounds:情势、局势,情形 situation, state of affairs,形势:形势严峻, (地势）形势 also terrain; topographical features,e.g. 形势险要 strategically important terrain:状况:6 all with at least 2 character attributive in front e.g. 标准状况. 情况,状况 seem to have greatest usage frequency, 情况 also often used in grammars, e.g.事物或情况，又可分以下几种情况

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **情势** (situation) = 情 (details) + 势 (formations /form)= **the form and details**
>
> you look at a situation as an object. The form of it tells you what kind of situation you are looking at.
>
> Example: 情势危急 (situation is critical) * *the form and the details tells us the situation is critical*

~

> **局势** (situation) = 局面 (board surface)+ 势 (formations /form) = **The formations on the board surface**
>
> Metaphorizing a situation as a chess game. The formations of the chess pieces on the board tell us what is going on in the game (situation)
>
> Example: 局势危急 (situation is critical) * *the formations on the chess board indicates the game(situation) is in a critical state*

~

> **形势**(situation) = 形(shape) + 势(formations/ form) = **shape and form**
>
> a 'shape and form' description can apply to an actual object; or metaphorically, to a state of affairs.
>
> Example: 形势危急 (situation is critical) * *the shape and form indicates the situation is in a critical state.*

~

> **情形** (situation) = 情(details)+ 形(shape)= **shape and details**
>
> shape and details forms a 'situation'.
>
> Example:看情形他不会来 (looks like he won't come)
>
> *The thing that's being looked at is details of the situation, which indicate he won't come*

~

> **情况** (situation) = 情(details)+ 况(appearance) = **appearance and details**
>
> appearance and details = 'circumstance'(situation).
>
> Example:看情况决定 (make the decision depend on the situation)
>   )
>
> *see the appearance and situation then decide*

~

> **状况** (situation) = 状態(status) + 况 (appearance) = **appearance and status**
>
> 'appearance and status' = 'condition' (situation).
>
> 这状况不能持续 (this situation cannot be maintained)

Comment: What is the difference in usage between 情势 and 情形? Maybe an example or two would help

Comment: added examples.

Comment: I always thought that 况 ment "how much more" as a depiction of a flood, like alot of something. So 情况 = details + much = the flood of details = the stream of details ...
By the way, where can I find 情 meaning as being about "details"?

Comment: And 势 being the "form"... where do you get it from? Can you share a link?

Comment: 慘況(pitiful appearance) ;內情(inside info/ inside details); 猛虎下山勢，通天勢，有龍虎之勢，作勢要打人

Comment: 情 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/553/ *2] fact; detail; situation; condition*

Comment: 勢 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1480/ *2] situation; state of affairs; circumstances 3] posture; carriage; gestures*- a posture is a body in a specific form